# Unable to extract Session ID Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

Am unable to extract Session ID ? Please find the details below

```
 Response : link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/dm-web/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml;jsessionid=107A7FE4C426D95B24A9094AE4E801DE?ln=css"

Regular Expression : 

Refrence Name : Corr_sessionID

jsessionid="(.+?)"?ln=css" />

Template: $1$

match No: 1

Default Value: EAE8FABC3D2560786752A48AC890D1D0

Passing In the URL :- /dm-web/javax.faces.resource/style.css.xhtml;jsessionid=${Corr_sessionID}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your regex look like this `jsessionid=([0-9A-Z]+)\?ln=css` you need to escape the `?` character and should not add the `"` characters between your expression

Comment: Thnx Cyclone .... it worked :)

Comment: Can You Help me with regex for following tag                                                                                  ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-6895850443025599938:127075601729255137" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

Comment: Something like `id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(-[0-9]+:[0-9]+)`, matches will return the content of  `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex should look like this `jsessionid=([0-9A-Z]+)\?ln=css`, since you need to escape the `?` character and should **not** add the `"` characters between your expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to automatically take care of the JSESSIONID cookie.

If you need the cookie value for some reason, you could do the following:

- add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to *user.properties* file
- restart JMeter

Now cookies which live in the HTTP Cookie Manager are available as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you can refer to JSESSIONID Cookie value as simple as:

```
${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}
```